# How to have higher precision real number in Matlab

Tags: matlab, scanf

My question looks very stupid and easy:

I have a file with numbers like:
6.0410442428001545  3.2950521350210047  5.689307914188567
and so on...
but when I read the file with
fscanf(fid, '%f', [3, 1]),
the numbers' precision is reduced and have only 4 digits after the '.'

What should I do to keep the precision of the original numbers with fscanf?

Thank you!

Comment: Try `format long`.

Comment: Or, `fprintf('%.17f\n', d)`.

Comment: I tried %g, %lg, and %l. All of them give the same things as %f.

Comment: By default, MATLAB only displays 4 decimal places. If you type `format long` and then display your data, it will show more. If that's not enough for you, use the `fprintf` I gave above.

Comment: %.17f gives an empty matrix. I am using fscanf, not fprintf

Comment: How do you know what the values are? In other words, where are you seeing that you have only 4 digits after the '.'?

Comment: In the command window

Comment: Then type `format long` and *then* display the values in the command window. Alternatively, don't display the values in the command window, use `fprintf` to *print* the values to the command window.

Comment: The bottom line is that `fscanf` is *reading* the values with the proper precision, MATLAB just doesn't *display* the full precision by default.

Comment: yes, format long makes things better, but %.17f does not work, giving an empty matrix. I am also writing things into a file.

Comment: The `%.17f` is to be used in `fprintf` *after* you've read the data using `fscanf` exactly as you have it in your question. The data is there, you just have to tell MATLAB to display it.

Comment: Additionally, it may be worth questioning the value of data to 17 places- if these are empirical measurements, a lot of those trailing digits could be junk

Comment: @IanRiley there are likely floating point roundoff errors as well. Even floating point addition isn't commutative.

Comment: @lan Riley  the data comes from molecular dynamics simulation